# Return custom HTTP_STATUS_CODE while Django login

Tags: django, django-permissions, django-login

My Django REST API has this class for authentication:

```
class AuthView(APIView):
      authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)

      def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          login(request, request.user)
          data = {'testkey':'testvalue'}
          return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

If credentials are correct, I'm getting 200 Status Code (which is fine).
However, for wrong credentials, I want to return a status code other than the default (401) Status Code.

Answer (score 3):

`HttpResponse` takes a status keyword argument, so

```
HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json", status=418)
```

will raise the classic *I'm a teapot*

[Django's http module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py)

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is, when authentication fails (due to BasicAuthentication) , the control is not going inside post(......) mehtod

Comment: So your actual issue is how the authentication flow works, which isn't really a suitable question. Have you looked at the authentication class?

Comment: Yes, I've gone through those, and since I'm verifying the user based on username/password, I'm using BasicAuthentication.
Still not getting any clue..

Comment: For unauthenticated responses, I can see only this in the documentation:
"Unauthenticated responses that are denied permission will result in an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response with an appropriate WWW-Authenticate header."

Comment: `+1` for using `418:Teapot`